# Objective C Table Cell ContentView The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjYGN.png)

I've added a label with a storyboard i have (Constraint top:10 left:0 right:0) one label in the table. According to the state if wanted to create image and add Constraint I get this error:

```
2016-06-17 16:02:59.235 Cellin[3748:162565] *** 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraintconstraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Constraint must contain a first layout item'
```

solved this error missing IBOUTLET;
new error:

```
The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fce22494cf0 V:[UILabel:0x7fce22490340'Hello']-(50)-[UIImageView:0x7fce226636c0]>
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
2016-06-17 16:17:14.152 Cellin[3889:170014] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableViewCellContentView
```

My Table Code

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    TableCellController *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.TLabel.text = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if(true){
        UIImageView *images = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [images setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:images];
        images.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

        NSLayoutConstraint *TComp = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.TLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:images attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:50.0];

        [cell.contentView addConstraint:TComp];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Constraint must contain a first layout item** clearly tells that you are missing the `firstItem` in this call.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *TComp = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.TLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:images attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:50.0];
```

Maybe you need to check if `cell.TLabel` is loaded properly. Missing `IBOutlet` ?

Comment: Your right "thanks" i'm fixed but now error: 

The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fce22494cf0 V:[UILabel:0x7fce22490340'Hello']-(50)-[UIImageView:0x7fce226636c0]>
 When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
2016-06-17 16:17:14.152 Cellin[3889:170014] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableViewCellContentView

Comment: Please ask a different question. This one is resolved. Also if you think it's correct. You should accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out following reasons to crash the app.

**1)** If you're hanging on to your views with properties make sure they're `strong`! This could account for them being `nil`.

**2)** Move the Constraint code from the initWithNib method to viewDidLoad

**3)** the views passed to the `[NSLayoutContraint constraintWithItem ...]` method are nil... this is also reason for crash